# How do I run flutter application with gradle in offline mode?

Tags: gradle, flutter

I'm trying to run my flutter application, but when it resolving android dependencies it will timeout. in android studio I can change gradle in offline model. is there any way to set gradle offline mode in flutter. the android studio setting(gradle offline work model) isn't work for flutter.

Comment: You should share at least some log message so people can understand more. Also do you have all the dependencies available offline so that `gradle` can build? Why would it be timed out? Are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: the problem can simplify as "gradle has '--offline' options" but flutter cannot use this options. gradle has "./gradlew build --offline", flutter use gradle build project, but how  can I add 'offline' options in gradle, when using flutter.

Comment: @AngerRan It is better to answer this question, in my opinion. Because some beginners are not able to follow your comment. For instance, ME :D

Answer (score 13):

## On Windows

- Edit `FLUTTER_PROJ_DIR/android/gradlew.bat`

  - Add switch `--offline` in `%JAVA_EXEC%`

```sh
@rem Execute Gradle
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% \
    %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" \
        -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" \
    org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS% --offline
```

## On *Nix

- Edit `FLUTTER_PROJ_DIR/android/gradlew`

  - Add switch `--offline` in `$JAVACMD`

```sh
exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
          org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$@" --offline
```

Comment: You should include at least a brief explanation of what the command does.

Comment: coool answer body

Comment: This helped with the problem of the `HTTP 502 Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer` while running the emulator...

Comment: You should include a description on how to use this.